# Implemented heapsort algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, heap-sort

I am learning algorithms by using Java. Here is an implementation of heapsort. Let me know if anything is wrong and and suggestion to improve the algorithm.

```
public class HeapSort {
    public int arr[];

    public HeapSort(int[] arr) {
        this.arr = arr;
    }

    // to make a heap
    public void makeHeap() {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            // index of child element
            int index = i;
            while (index != 0) {
                int parent = (index - 1) / 2;
                if (arr[index] <= arr[parent]) break;
                // swap child element to its parent one
                int temp = arr[index];
                arr[index] = arr[parent];
                arr[parent] = temp;
                index = parent;
            }
        }
    }

    // to remove item from the top of the binary tree -> arr[0]
    public void removeTopItem(int count) {
        int a = arr[0];
        arr[0] = arr[count];
        arr[count] = a;
        int index = 0;
        count--;
        // to remake binary tree
        while (true) {
            int leftChild = index * 2 + 1;
            int rightChild = index * 2 + 2;

            // check the boundary
            if (rightChild > count) break;
            if (arr[index] > arr[leftChild] && arr[index] > arr[rightChild]) break;

            // to get greater parent
            int parentGreat = arr[rightChild] > arr[leftChild] ? rightChild : leftChild;

            // swap current item to its parent one
            int temp = arr[index];
            arr[index] = arr[parentGreat];
            arr[parentGreat] = temp;
            index = parentGreat;
        }
    }

    // sort using by heap
    public int[] heapSort() {
        // make a heap
        makeHeap();
        // sorting
        for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            removeTopItem(i);
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: (How about [doc comments](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide)?) How did/do you test this? (Doubtful about `if (rightChild > count) break;`)

Comment: I haven't created doc yet. I did test it, it is working well. 
if (rightChild > count)  -> because as sorted part is stored on the right side, I don't have to check until the end of the array length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`I did test it, it is working well.` Well,

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
        new HeapSort(new int[] {3, 2, 1}).heapSort()));
```

isn't working.

- [document/comment](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide) your code.
  You commented (all public method) members, see above for standard tool support.
  For every non-trivial piece of code, what is the reason it is there, in the first place?
  Starting at the `class`-, if not `package`-level:

  ```
  /** HeapSort as a <code>java.util.function.UnaryOperator<T></code>.
   * Java & coding beginner's exercise
   *  in type design and algorithm implementation.
   * The general idea is to turn the array into a max-heap
   *  and repeatedly move the max item
   *  from the shrinking heap to its current end. 
   */
  class HeapSort<T> implements In_placeSorter<T> {
      @Override
      public T sort(T toBeSorted) {
          if (!(toBeSorted instanceof int[]))
              throw new IllegalArgumentException("int[] only, for now");
          comparables = (int[]) toBeSorted;
          return (T) sort();
      } …
  ```

  (note `sort()` not (doc)commented *here*: inherits from `In_placeSorter<T>`)
- name things for what use they are. `arr` is horribly unspecific (used `comparables` instead).
- don't make things more visible than they need to be. When in doubt, start with default/not specifying visibility:
  `int comparables[];`
- pay attention to boundaries:
  neither the loop in `makeHeap()` nor the one in `heapSort()` need to handle index 0.
  More importantly, while it is true that a right child needs to exist to be handled: what about *left*?
- trying to implement "the general idea" *without* looking what&how others have done is a great step in learning —
  please precede it by considering *how do I know/check the specification is met?*
- asking *how to improve the procedure* is another great step in programming
  (professionals prefix a *when and*). Start with *algorithm*;
  Just don't try to force it - if nothing suggests itself, turn to something else temporarily, sleep on it, or *now* look what others have done and how, for heap-sort:

  - why do `heapify()`s start at the middle of the array?
  - what is to be gained from *not* comparing the item to be (re-)inserted while there are two children?

  Continue with coding: e.g., there are several instances where you exchange/*swap* elements: "factor out" a method/procedure
- handle petty concerns last, if at all:
  Java arrays & `java.util.Arrays` don't come with a `swap()`? Use [`java.util.Collections.swap(java.util.List, int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap-java.util.List-int-int-) as a template
  using a `for`-loop:
  `for (int index = i, parent ; index != 0 ; index = parent) {…`

Just in case:

```
/** Rearranges items in ascending "natural" order. */
interface In_placeSorter<T> extends java.util.function.UnaryOperator<T> {
    /** Rearranges items in ascending "natural" order.
     * @param toBeSorted items to be sorted
     * @return <code>toBeSorted</code> */
    T sort(T toBeSorted);
    @Override
    default T apply(T t) { return sort(t); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! .Yes, I am implementing with basic theory that I learnt from the book first and going through with codes that others have done.
You gave me great feedback and suggestions. Everything is correct that you mentioned above. I will fix it and do my best, thanks !